# JQuery sortable not posting correct form data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use sorteable to attach users to lists and I have a form which is coded as:

```
<form action={{ secure_url('send-data') }} method="POST" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" name="Salvar">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Confirmados
            <ul class="list-group list-group-sortable-connected connectedSortable" id="confirmados">@if(empty($confirmados)) <br /> @endif
                @foreach ( $users as $v )
                @if (in_array($v->id, $confirmados))
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><input type="hidden" name="confirmados[]" value="{{$v->id}}">{{$v->nome}}</li>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Ausentes
            <ul class="list-group list-group-sortable-connected connectedSortable" id="ausentes">@if(empty($ausentes)) <br /> @endif
                @foreach ( $users as $v )
                @if (in_array($v->id, $ausentes))
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger"><input type="hidden" name="ausentes[]" value="{{$v->id}}">{{$v->nome}}</li>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Pendentes
                <ul class="list-group list-group-sortable-connected connectedSortable" id="pendentes">
                    @foreach ( $users as $v )
                    @if (!in_array($v->id, $ausentes) && !in_array($v->id, $confirmados))
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"><input type="hidden" name="pendentes[]" value="{{$v->id}}">{{$v->nome}}</li>
                    @endif
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my JS is like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $("#ausentes, #confirmados, #pendentes").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.sender[0].id === 'pendentes') {
                ui.item.removeClass("list-group-item-info");
            } else if (ui.sender[0].id === 'confirmados') {
                ui.item.removeClass("list-group-item-success");
            } else if (ui.sender[0].id === 'ausentes') {
                ui.item.removeClass("list-group-item-danger");
            }

            if (this.id === 'pendentes') {
                ui.item.addClass("list-group-item-info");
                ui.item.attr("name", "pendentes[]");
            } else if (this.id === 'confirmados') {
                ui.item.addClass("list-group-item-success");
                ui.item.attr("name", "confirmados[]");
            } else if (this.id === 'ausentes') {
                ui.item.addClass("list-group-item-danger");
                ui.item.attr("name", "ausentes[]");
            }
            toastr.options.preventDuplicates = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: $('.form-horizontal').attr('action'),
                data: $('.form-horizontal').serialize(),
                method: $('.form-horizontal').attr('method'),
                success:function(data) {
                    $('#ajax').html(data);

                    toastr.success("Alterações salvas com sucesso");
                }
            });
        },
    }).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

But after I drag and drop the users around the lists, when ajax perform the post, it keeps sending the data as it's original contents. It doesn't get the modifications.

If all the users were in the "pendentes" list, even if I change to the "confirmados" list it sends everyone as "pendentes".

Thats what I get after doing the changes:

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "ynDyoSBCQ92jG5r5MKdItiuwq386GKaPU52rg2wv"
  "pendentes" => array:11 [▼
    0 => "20500"
    1 => "24261"
    2 => "24908"
    3 => "24666"
    4 => "24667"
    5 => "24263"
    6 => "24264"
    7 => "24265"
    8 => "24266"
    9 => "24267"
    10 => "24268"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it keeps sending the data as it's original contents. It doesn't get the modifications.

This because you are using:

```
$('.form-horizontal').serialize()
```

If you need an array of objects you need to serialize by yourself. For instance, you can select all **pendentes** and build the final array:

```
var pendentesArr = $('#pendentes :input').serializeArray().reduce(function (acc, ele) {
        acc.push(ele.value);
        return acc;
}, []);
```

The snippet:

```js
$("#ausentes, #confirmados, #pendentes").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.sender[0].id === 'pendentes') {
            ui.item.removeClass("list-group-item-info");
        } else if (ui.sender[0].id === 'confirmados') {
            ui.item.removeClass("list-group-item-success");
        } else if (ui.sender[0].id === 'ausentes') {
            ui.item.removeClass("list-group-item-danger");
        }

        if (this.id === 'pendentes') {
            ui.item.addClass("list-group-item-info");
            ui.item.attr("name", "pendentes[]");
        } else if (this.id === 'confirmados') {
            ui.item.addClass("list-group-item-success");
            ui.item.attr("name", "confirmados[]");
        } else if (this.id === 'ausentes') {
            ui.item.addClass("list-group-item-danger");
            ui.item.attr("name", "ausentes[]");
        }
        //toastr.options.preventDuplicates = true;
        var pendentesArr = $('#pendentes :input').serializeArray().reduce(function (acc, ele) {
            acc.push(ele.value);
            return acc;
        }, []);
        var ausentesArr = $('#ausentes :input').serializeArray().reduce(function (acc, ele) {
            acc.push(ele.value);
            return acc;
        }, []);
        var confirmadosArr = $('#confirmados :input').serializeArray().reduce(function (acc, ele) {
            acc.push(ele.value);
            return acc;
        }, []);
        var dataTobeSent = {_token: $('[name="_token"]').val(), pendentes: pendentesArr,
            ausentes: ausentesArr, confirmados: confirmadosArr};

        console.log('dataTobeSent: ' + JSON.stringify(dataTobeSent));
        $.ajax({
            url: $('.form-horizontal').attr('action'),
            data: $.param(dataTobeSent),
            method: $('.form-horizontal').attr('method'),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ajax').html(data);

                toastr.success("Alterações salvas com sucesso");
            }
        });
    },
}).disableSelection();
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>




<form action='' method="POST" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" name="Salvar">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Confirmados
            <ul class="list-group list-group-sortable-connected connectedSortable" id="confirmados">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><input type="hidden" name="confirmados[]" value="1">1
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><input type="hidden" name="confirmados[]" value="2">2
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Ausentes
            <ul class="list-group list-group-sortable-connected connectedSortable" id="ausentes">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger"><input type="hidden" name="ausentes[]" value="a">a
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger"><input type="hidden" name="ausentes[]" value="b">b
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Pendentes
                <ul class="list-group list-group-sortable-connected connectedSortable" id="pendentes">
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"><input type="hidden" name="pendentes[]" value="11">11
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"><input type="hidden" name="pendentes[]" value="12">12
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"><input type="hidden" name="pendentes[]" value="13">13
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```